# Assessing P-values in linear regression when the purpose is prediction

Tags: forecasting, p-value, prediction

I have a question regarding p-values in the linear regression.The purpose of using the linear regression model is mainly to predict future values with accuracy. As I read, when the purpose is prediction, I can somehow not may too much attention to multicollinearity and the assumption of the linear model.
Some of my predictors are categorical variables: can I include the levels having non-significant p-values when I am only interested in prediction?

The output is as follows:

```
lm(formula = log(cost1) ~ log(cost2) + program + location+ month + type, data=data)
Residuals:
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-0.88768 -0.10647  0.00169  0.09248  0.91612
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              0.1526869  0.1186113   1.287  0.19858
log(cost2)               0.9812236  0.0072015 136.253  < 2e-16 ***
program1                -0.0055709  0.0475793  -0.117  0.90684 
program2                -0.0007374  0.0593048  -0.012  0.99008  
program3                 0.0531385  0.0734250   0.724  0.46958 
program4                 0.0712944  0.0472402   1.509  0.13188
locationA                0.0210172  0.0319844   0.657  0.51141
locationB                0.0415091  0.0298623   1.390  0.16514
locationC                0.0898111  0.0316606   2.837  0.00474 ** 
month02                 -0.0631733  0.0454815  -1.389  0.16545  
month03                  0.0195483  0.0449924   0.434  0.66412 
month04                  0.0037596  0.0446384   0.084  0.93291
month05                  0.0387446  0.0422586   0.917  0.35966    
month06                  0.0899078  0.0494497   1.818  0.06963 .
month07                  0.0974763  0.0459993   2.119  0.03457 * 
month08                  0.0351214  0.0472294   0.744  0.45744 
month09                  0.0652653  0.0629235   1.037  0.30013
month10                 -0.5510485  0.1986461  -2.774  0.00574 ** 
TypeI                   -0.0815081  0.0821450  -0.992  0.32155
TypeII                   0.0340512  0.0436612   0.780  0.43582 
TypeIII                  0.0703337  0.0268013   2.624  0.00895 **
TypeIV                  -0.0658808  0.0411735  -1.600  0.11021   
TypeV                    0.1327603  0.0331560   4.004 7.16e-05 ***
TypeVI                   0.0994576  0.0264572   3.759  0.00019 ***
```

This model gave me the best prediction among other combination of predictors. Can I still use this model even though not all p-values are significant or no?

Comment: Even in a non-predictive setting, when a categorical variable is split into levels, you should care about the overall significance of all the levels together ($F$-test) rather than individual significances of each level ($t$-tests). Also, statistical significance of individual coefficients is not a very good criterion for selecting which variables to include in a predictive model. Comparison of different candidate models (including different variables) by means of information criteria (especially AIC if the goal is forecasting) could make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If (and it is a big "if") your only goal is prediction, it doesn't matter at all what model you use or which variables you include, so long as the model is stable. I recommend partitioning your model matrix in 2. For example, train (fit) your model with 70% of your observations and see how accurate the predictions are on the other 30%. Try several models (for example with or without the variable you mentioned) this way and keep the one that gives the best accuracy in the validation set (i.e. the one with 30%) .

Answer (score 1):

There is a famous saying in statistics, "Prediction is very difficult, especially about the future".

If you figure this one out, let us know. :-)

On a more serious note, building on Felipe's answer. If you want to go one step further, partition your data into 3 parts, not 2. Training and testing. Train and test your model on these two parts, until you get a model you like. Then, test it on the third portion of the data, to make sure it works with data that it's never seen before.

Comment: I never liked p-values anyway ^^ Who cares as long as the model works, right? I'm not too fond of "explainatory" models...